# How to get reproducible results of T5 transformer model

Tags: python, nlp, torch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I'm trying to get reproducible results of T5 transformer model:

```
import torch
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration,T5Tokenizer


def set_seed(seed):
  torch.manual_seed(seed)
  if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

set_seed(42)

t5model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('ramsrigouthamg/t5_paraphraser')
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-base')

device = torch.device("cpu")
print ("device ",device)
t5model = t5model.to(device)

max_len = 256

text =  "paraphrase: " + txt + " </s>"

encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(text,pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors="pt")
input_ids, attention_masks = encoding["input_ids"].to(device), encoding["attention_mask"].to(device)

beam_outputs = t5model.generate(
    input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks,
    do_sample=True,
    max_length=max_len,
    top_k=50,
    top_p=0.98,
    early_stopping=True,
    num_return_sequences=10,
)
```

Though I set a seed number, `t5model.generate` gives me different results each time I run it.

What is the right way to set the seed number, in order to get the same results of `t5model.generate` after multiple executions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the state_dict of your model to produce every time the same output.

What happens here, is that the T5 model initialization is calling the pytorch random number generator. That means, every time you run the following code, you will get the same output:

```py
set_seed(42)
t5model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('ramsrigouthamg/t5_paraphraser')

t5model = t5model.to(device)

beam_outputs = []

for x in range(3):
  beam_outputs.append(t5model.generate(
    input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks,
    do_sample=True,
    max_length=max_len,
    top_k=50,
    top_p=0.98,
    early_stopping=True,
    num_return_sequences=5,
  ))
tokenizer.batch_decode([y for x in beam_outputs for y in x])
```

Setting the seed of the random number generator doesn't mean that it will generate the same output every time you call it, it means that the sequence of generated numbers is initialized by the same seed (check this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/does-pytorch-change-its-internal-seed-during-training/46505/4) for further information):

```py
torch.manual_seed(42)
print(torch.randn(2))
print(torch.randn(2))
print(torch.randn(2))

torch.manual_seed(42)
print(torch.randn(2))
print(torch.randn(2))
print(torch.randn(2))
```

Output:

```
tensor([0.3367, 0.1288])
tensor([0.2345, 0.2303])
tensor([-1.1229, -0.1863])

tensor([0.3367, 0.1288])
tensor([0.2345, 0.2303])
tensor([-1.1229, -0.1863])
```